# Positioning another div without breaking vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I had encountered to an interesting CSS challenge. In the following code I was able to vertically aligned the text and input. The part I couldn't manage was, without breaking the vertical alignment (text - input) I need to put footer text under the input.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.head {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20%;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.col input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="col">
    Footer Text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    Three Line Text
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="col">
    Footer Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, container div height should effect from footer text as well. So using absolute will not work for this case.

I already aware some JavaScript or CSS hack solutions. But for this case, I want to proceed with a proper way. How can we achieve this properly?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention before. Footer text could be multiple lines as well. It should cover both inputs underneath.

Comment: I'd start by putting your inputs and footer text into a single div.

Comment: I tried that, but it will break the vertical alignment with text on the left. Keeping that vertical alignment is also requirement for this case.

Comment: If you have a div for left content and a div for right content, you can manipulate the content inside each div in any way that you'd like.  You can adjust the text on the left any way you like, and you can adjust your footer any way you'd like.

Comment: Are you unable to use flexbox to solve this?

Comment: @Daniel flexbox was not my first solution, because that will require lots of html and css change. But if there is no option I can go with flexbox.

Comment: @JoeFitzsimmons I'm trying to vertically align both div and put another div which will not effect the alignment. And for my case container div shouldn't have fixed height. Because contents can get longer or shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that but it requires restructuring the HTML and altering a class or two...oh, and a pseudo-element.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.head {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col,
.second {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 .25em;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
}

.col:before {
  content: "";
  height: 1.2em; /* or whatever your line-height is */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="foot">
      Footer Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    Three Line Text
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="foot">
      Footer Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there any chance to apply same solution for footer text with two lines too? It should cover right input underneath as well.

Comment: Not generally...the alignment requires that the height of the footer text is known...or can be calculated.